# Strange statistics in Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, console, statistics, playback

Today I noticed strange statistics in my Google Play Developer Console in one of my  application

[image]

It is about Final installs on active devices:

17 July - there was big leap caused by including pre-install. I don't known why, beause I don't think my app is pre-installed by any provider.

18 July - installs on active devices falled to 0

As you can see daily installs are still correct.

Have you got any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I see similar behavior on my side, and final #installs is also 1!! Looks like something fishy is going on their side. And I see that for the 10 apps of my 'Elementique' app suite. Let's wait and see.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439488/why-is-google-play-console-active-installs-decreased-to-0-in-a-day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this exact same problem today. Also, it no longer shows the total number of of installs for apps in the list under "All applications".

I shouldn't worry about it. They've been making changes and must have messed something up.