# Why is Google Play Console Active Installs decreased to 0 in a day?

Tags: android, console, admob, playback

I made a minimal Equilizer app which got around 100 active installs but when I opened my Play Console today, its showing 0 Active Installs.

[here is the screenshot of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgaoS.png)

In fact, all my apps are showing zero active installs now.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Active install user means currently they have installed app into device. If all the users have uninstalled app from their device that's why you can see 0 Active User. Or if you want to check proper result then please use Google Analytics of Firebase Analytics..

Comment: Please see the screenshot attached. Is it possible that the Play Console is Bugged?

Comment: FYI, everything just came back to normal on my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is currently working on some things. All apps on the store are affected

Comment: I just checked My Firebase Analytics and its showing correct Active Installs.
Thank You

Comment: i tweeted google about this, will let you know when i get more info :)

Comment: Everything is OK on my side now. This Google Play console bug just last about 1 hour.